# How do compound verbs develop?

Tags: etymology

There's a very interesting (to me at least) example of compound verbs, in [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_verb_construction#Contrast_with_compound_verbs) on Serial Verbs:

> `सत्तू            खा      लिया`
> `sattū         khā     liyā`
> `parched.grain eat     take.pfv`
> "ate up the sattu"

vs.

> `बच्चे        को    खा      डाला`
> `bacce      ko    khā     ḍālā`
> `child.OBL  DAT   eat     throw.pfv`
> "devoured the child"

How do these compound verbs develop?

Comment: Are you asking about compound verbs in this language (what is it, by the way?), or  serial verbs of this type, or serial verbs in general? There are many different kinds and they arise in many different ways.

Comment: @jlawler compound words in general. The wiki page explains more about it (stating that they're not serial verbs, as far as I can tell).

Comment: In English there's not much of either, so the distinction hardly matters. Elsewhere, it depends on the language(s) and the construction(s).

Comment: @jlawler, I just reread the article and there *is* a distinction. Compound verbs one of the verbs conveys the content, the other modifies it slightly. In serial verbs, each verb is required for the meaning. Take a look at the examples.

Comment: That's a distinction that may be useful for some constructions in some languages, if conveying content and being required for the meaning can be adequately measured.

Comment: @jlawler, does that mean the wiki page is wrong?